# Best way to access/update one table from two or more scripts?

Tags: php, mysql

**Background**

I have a table with data that two or more PHP scripts will access simultaneously. The data looks something like this:

```
+--------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
| ID     | Start             |  End      |  Status   |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 1      | 1000              | 1500      |  0        |
| 2      | 1000              | 1500      |  0        |
| 3      | 1000              | 1500      |  0        |
| 4      | 1000              | 1500      |  0        |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

The PHP scripts perform the following query when they start up:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Status` = 0 LIMIT 1
```

The PHP script then performs a loop from the `start` value to the `end` value (1000 to 1500). After its done, it updates the `Status` of that row to `'1'`. It automatically redirects to itself and restarts the the whole process.

**The challenges I have are**:

1. If I want 2 or more of the same PHP script to run simultaneously accessing the same Database, how do I ensure that they're **not** accessing the same record?
2. The bigger challenge is that if I want to split up the loop from `start` to `end` over multiple instances of the same PHP script, i.e., every 100 values is one instance of the script, and after reaching `1100`, update the MySQL `Start` to `1100` and redirect to the same script which starts at `1101` to `1200` and so on till the `End` number is reached. After the `End` number has been reached, that record's `Status` will be set to `1` and it will move on the next record. In the real situation, its for about a million count from start to end, and some memory intensive functions are performed in the loop, so I need to chunk it out.

All I know about row-level locking, I learned in the last few minutes; and none of that seems to answer multiple instance locking from one script.

Should I consider session IDs/cookies? What do you recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest:

1. Using `InnoDB`, which supports row-level locking:

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE `table` ENGINE=InnoDB;
   ```
2. Using a value of `Status` to indicate "in progress"; to be a little more explicit, let's use MySQL's `ENUM` type:

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE `table`
     ADD status_new ENUM('queued','in progress','complete') AFTER status;

   UPDATE `table` SET status_new = CASE status
     WHEN 0 THEN 'queued'
     WHEN 1 THEN 'complete'
   END;

   ALTER TABLE `table` DROP status;
   ```
3. Using transactions within the client:

   ```php
   $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, FALSE);   // pdo
   $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);                        // mysqli (OOP)
   mysqli_autocommit($link, FALSE);                   // mysqli (procedural)
   mysql_query('START TRANSACTION');                  // ext/mysql *
   ```
4. Using a [locking read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) to fetch a row to be processed:

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE status_new = 'queued' LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
   ```
5. Setting the `status` of the fetched row to `'in progress'`:

   ```sql
   UPDATE `table` SET status_new = 'in progress' WHERE ID = ?
   ```
6. Committing the transaction:

   ```php
   $dbh->commit();                                    // pdo
   $mysqli->commit();                                 // mysqli (OOP)
   mysqli_commit($link);                              // mysqli (procedural)
   mysql_query('COMMIT');                             // ext/mysql *
   ```
7. When processing is complete, `UPDATE` the record again to mark it as such.

Beware that you correctly detect and handle any errors that arise at each stage.

* note that `ext/mysql` has not been recommended for use in new code since June 2011 and is now deprecated in PHP v5.5.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Very functional! This addresses the first challenge where we can lock a row and mark it as In-Progress. But with the 2nd challenge, when the script loads again to process the next chunk in the record, do I pass a GET query string with  the present ID? Or can I carry over the 'lock' to the next instance?

Comment: @Reddox: It depends on your security requirements.  Your suggestion works okay, provided that there is no risk (or no harm) from an erroneous `GET` string (be it malicious or accidental).  Other things you might consider, depending on your requirements, include tracking the extent of progress in the database or in a server-side `$_SESSION` variable; you could also consider including some sort of authentication token, e.g. an HMAC, in the querystring.

Comment: I'll have to lookup HMAC. Thanks :)